# ~/.ssh folder recover

Tags: git

i have created sucessfully , a public private key pair , with ssh , with github it worked perfect .

but , when i did with git.assembla.com , i faced permission issue , so i tried to create a new pair of ssh key .

but i deleted the ~/.ssh folder , via

```
 rm -r ~/.ssh
```

now even if i do

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@youremail.com"
```

its executes sucessfully but  no ./ssh folder is created in my root home directory .

this was working fine before but now error is

```
ssh -v git@github.com
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-  
5github8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github8 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same public key. One set of keys for an account on a machine.

Comment: i deleted ~/.shh how to recover it .

Comment: don't recover it. Make your key with `ssh-keygen -t rsa`. Then edit your key on both assembla and github to be the contents of `.git/id_rsa.pub`.

Comment: ok i added the new keys , and the ssh -v git@git.asembla.com executed sucessfully , but when i did git push after git init and git remote add "url-give" , it says permission denied .

Comment: I meant `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. You don't need to `git init` your repo. It's already a repo. Make sure you are pushing to your fork.